# How to get incomplete request in web browser control?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

consider below secenario...

i have page called "Page.aspx" contains link for page "Page1.aspx" and "Page2.aspx"

once a page.aspx is loaded i click on "Page1.aspx" before browser get response of "Page1.aspx" i click on "Page2.aspx" which in turns load page2.aspx.

Is there anyway i can get event of navigation is cancel of page1.aspx? OR event raise when request is been stop before geting any response or rendering in browser?

Thanks
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

See  events `Navigate`, `Navigated`, `ProgressChanged`, `DocumentTitleChanged`